# failed to build phantomJS binary in Mac

Tags: python, xcode, macos, build, phantomjs

So I followed the instructions on:

http://phantomjs.org/build.html

And I get the following error when running build.py:

```
qcocoahelpers.mm:676:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'InvalidContext'
    require_action(inContext != NULL, InvalidContext, err = paramErr);
                                      ^
qcocoahelpers.mm:677:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'InvalidBounds'
    require_action(inBounds != NULL, InvalidBounds, err = paramErr);
                                     ^
qcocoahelpers.mm:678:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'InvalidImage'
    require_action(inImage != NULL, InvalidImage, err = paramErr);
                                    ^
3 errors generated.
make[4]: *** [.obj/qcocoahelpers.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [sub-cocoa-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
2 warnings generated.
rm -f libqsqlite.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar cq libqsqlite.a .obj/smain.o .obj/qsql_sqlite.o .obj/sqlite3.o .obj/moc_qsql_sqlite_p.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib -s libqsqlite.a
rm -f ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.a
mv -f libqsqlite.a ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/
make[1]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2

ERROR: Failed to build PhantomJS! Building Qt Base failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found myself in the same situation. I figured it was just undeclared vars, so I opened qcocoahelpers.mm and not knowing how to declare vars in whatever language it is, I just commented the three lines out and voila: it compiled!